# Python Numerical Integration for Volume of Region

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, numerical-methods, montecarlo

For a program, I need an algorithm to very quickly compute the volume of a solid. This shape is specified by a function that, given a point P(x,y,z), returns 1 if P is a point of the solid and 0 if P is not a point of the solid.

I have tried using numpy using the following test:

```
import numpy
from scipy.integrate import *
def integrand(x,y,z):
    if x**2. + y**2. + z**2. <=1.:
        return 1.
    else:
        return 0.
g=lambda x: -2.
f=lambda x: 2.
q=lambda x,y: -2.
r=lambda x,y: 2.
I=tplquad(integrand,-2.,2.,g,f,q,r)
print I
```

but it fails giving me the following errors:

> Warning (from warnings module):
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 321
>       warnings.warn(msg, IntegrationWarning)
>   IntegrationWarning: The maximum number of subdivisions (50) has been achieved.
>     If increasing the limit yields no improvement it is advised to analyze 
>     the integrand in order to determine the difficulties.  If the position of a 
>     local difficulty can be determined (singularity, discontinuity) one will 
>     probably gain from splitting up the interval and calling the integrator 
>     on the subranges.  Perhaps a special-purpose integrator should be used.
>
> Warning (from warnings module):
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 321
>       warnings.warn(msg, IntegrationWarning)
>   IntegrationWarning: The algorithm does not converge.  Roundoff error is detected
>     in the extrapolation table.  It is assumed that the requested tolerance
>     cannot be achieved, and that the returned result (if full_output = 1) is 
>     the best which can be obtained.
>
> Warning (from warnings module):
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 321
>       warnings.warn(msg, IntegrationWarning)
>   IntegrationWarning: The occurrence of roundoff error is detected, which prevents 
>     the requested tolerance from being achieved.  The error may be 
>     underestimated.
>
> Warning (from warnings module):
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 321
>       warnings.warn(msg, IntegrationWarning)
>   IntegrationWarning: The integral is probably divergent, or slowly convergent.

So, naturally, I looked for "special-purpose integrators", but could not find any that would do what I needed.

Then, I tried writing my own integration using the Monte Carlo method and tested it with the same shape:

```
import random

# Monte Carlo Method
def get_volume(f,(x0,x1),(y0,y1),(z0,z1),prec=0.001,init_sample=5000):
    xr=(x0,x1)
    yr=(y0,y1)
    zr=(z0,z1)
    vdomain=(x1-x0)*(y1-y0)*(z1-z0)
    def rand((p0,p1)):
        return p0+random.random()*(p1-p0)
    vol=0.
    points=0.
    s=0.  # sum part of variance of f
    err=0.
    percent=0
    while err>prec or points<init_sample:
        p=(rand(xr),rand(yr),rand(zr))
        rpoint=f(p)
        vol+=rpoint
        points+=1
        s+=(rpoint-vol/points)**2
        if points>1:
            err=vdomain*(((1./(points-1.))*s)**0.5)/(points**0.5)
        if err>0:
            if int(100.*prec/err)>=percent+1:
                percent=int(100.*prec/err)
                print percent,'% complete\n  error:',err
    print int(points),'points used.'
    return vdomain*vol/points
f=lambda (x,y,z): ((x**2)+(y**2)<=4.) and ((z**2)<=9.) and ((x**2)+(y**2)>=0.25)
print get_volume(f,(-2.,2.),(-2.,2.),(-2.,2.))
```

but this works too slowly. For this program I will be using this numerical integration about 100 times or so, and I will also be doing it on larger shapes, which will take minutes if not an hour or two at the rate it goes now, not to mention that I want a better precision than 2 decimal places.

I have tried implementing a MISER Monte Carlo method, but was having some difficulties and I'm still unsure how much faster it would be.

So, I am asking if there are any libraries that can do what I am asking, or if there are any better algorithms which work several times faster (for the same accuracy). Any suggestions are welcome, as I've been working on this for quite a while now.

EDIT:

If I cannot get this working in Python, I am open to switching to any other language that is both compilable and has relatively easy GUI functionality. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: It's worth noting that the "size" (net volume) of a shape won't matter for either numerical integration or Monte Carlo. The complexity of the shape boundary however, will change the convergence of some algorithms.

Comment: @Hooked, the size of the shape determines the size of the region over which one integrates, and the larger that is, the more points are needed to get the same precision.

Comment: all shapes can be scaled to fit within some bounding box. From there, a simple MC sampling algorithm will run with the same time constant regardless of the net volume. I think we are defining precision differently - usually I consider the error _relative_ to the dimensions, not an absolute error. For example if I were integrating a volume of an apple and the Earth, for one of them I wouldn't are if I was a few meters off...

Comment: @Hooked that makes sense; I was referring to an absolute error, but as you mention, relative probably makes more sense.

Answer (score 4):

As the others have already noted, finding the volume of domain that's given by a Boolean function is hard. You could used [pygalmesh](https://github.com/nschloe/pygalmesh#your-own-custom-level-set-function) (a small project of mine) which sits on top of [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/) and gives you back a tetrahedral mesh. This

```py
import numpy
import pygalmesh
import meshplex


class Custom(pygalmesh.DomainBase):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Custom, self).__init__()
        return

    def eval(self, x):
        return (x[0]**2 + x[1]**2 + x[2]**2) - 1.0

    def get_bounding_sphere_squared_radius(self):
        return 2.0


mesh = pygalmesh.generate_mesh(Custom(), cell_size=1.0e-1)
```

gives you

[image]

From there on out, you can use a variety of packages for extracting the volume. One possibility: [meshplex](https://github.com/nschloe/meshplex) (another one out of my zoo):

```py
import meshplex
mp = meshplex.MeshTetra(mesh.points, mesh.cells["tetra"])
print(numpy.sum(mp.cell_volumes))
```

gives

```
4.161777
```

which is close enough to the true value `4/3 pi = 4.18879020478...`. If want more precision, decrease the `cell_size` in the mesh generation above.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is not a continuous function, I think it's difficult to do the integration.

How about:

```
import numpy as np

def sphere(x,y,z):
    return x**2 + y**2 + z**2 <= 1

x, y, z = np.random.uniform(-2, 2, (3, 2000000))

sphere(x, y, z).mean() * (4**3), 4/3.0*np.pi
```

output:

```
(4.1930560000000003, 4.1887902047863905)
```

Or VTK:

```
from tvtk.api import tvtk

n = 151
r = 2.0
x0, x1 = -r, r
y0, y1 = -r, r
z0, z1 = -r, r
X,Y,Z = np.mgrid[x0:x1:n*1j, y0:y1:n*1j, z0:z1:n*1j]
s = sphere(X, Y, Z)

img = tvtk.ImageData(spacing=((x1-x0)/(n-1), (y1-y0)/(n-1), (z1-z0)/(n-1)), 
                     origin=(x0, y0, z0), dimensions=(n, n, n))

img.point_data.scalars = s.astype(float).ravel()

blur = tvtk.ImageGaussianSmooth(input=img) 
blur.set_standard_deviation(1)
contours = tvtk.ContourFilter(input = blur.output) 

contours.set_value(0, 0.5)
mp = tvtk.MassProperties(input = contours.output)
mp.volume, mp.surface_area
```

output:

```
4.186006622559839, 12.621690438955586
```

Comment: Your numpy example is the efficient way to go, if the function is vectorised. For some cases, you can make it even faster using numexpr in the integrand, that will evaluate the expression in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be very difficult without giving a little hint on the boundary:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import *

def integrand(z,y,x):
    return 1. if x**2 + y**2 + z**2 <= 1. else 0.

g=lambda x: -2
h=lambda x: 2
q=lambda x,y: -np.sqrt(max(0, 1-x**2-y**2))
r=lambda x,y: np.sqrt(max(0, 1-x**2-y**2))
I=tplquad(integrand,-2.,2.,g,h,q,r)

print I
```

Comment: I just tried running your code, and it works! I just want to ask though: why does your code work while my code outputs several "warnings". You only basically changed the limits of integration in one dimension, so wouldn't it still be integrating inside a cylinder and have problems at the border points?